# Entity Framework 4 and Linq: OrderBy a field nested in a Query : refactor my code

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4, sql-order-by

First, [Thomas Levesque](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2290436/linq-orderby-breaks-with-navigation-property-being-null/2290554#2290554) had a good solution for ordering fields in a related table where the relation may not always be there:

```
userQuery = userQuery.OrderBy(u => 
    (u.Department != null) ? u.Department.Name : String.Empty);
```

I need to do the same thing.  My aggregate root is enormous:

```
myQuery = myQuery.OrderBy(p =>
  (p.Seconds == null
    ? 0
    : p.Seconds.FirstOrDefault() == null
      ? 0
      : p.Seconds.First().Thirds == null
        ? 0
        : p.Seconds.First().Thirds.FirstOrDefault() == null
          ? 0
          : p.Seconds.First().Thirds.First().Forths == null
            ? 0
            : p.Seconds.First().Thirds.First().Forths.FirstOrDefault() == null
              ? 0
              : p.Seconds.First().Thirds.First().Forths.First().myField));
```

Is this really the way to do this, or is there something much easier to read?  My other problem is that the nested myField has a matching "default" value sitting in the top level Query, also named by myField.  The idea was to Order by the coalesce of these two fields (??).

Edit: I think this would include the "default value" from the first field:

```
myQuery = myQuery.OrderBy(p =>
  (p.Seconds == null
    ? p.myDefaultField // Used to be zero
    : p.Seconds.FirstOrDefault() == null
      ? p.myDefaultField
      : p.Seconds.First().Thirds == null
        ? p.myDefaultField
        : p.Seconds.First().Thirds.FirstOrDefault() == null
          ? p.myDefaultField
          : p.Seconds.First().Thirds.First().Forths == null
            ? p.myDefaultField
            : p.Seconds.First().Thirds.First().Forths.FirstOrDefault() == null
              ? p.myDefaultField
              : p.Seconds.First().Thirds.First().Forths.First().myField));
```

**How could I rewrite this OrderBy to be cleaner?**  This code fails with an error of "Cannot compare elements of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1'. Only primitive types (such as Int32, String, and Guid) and entity types are supported."

Comment: Well, maybe you should be trying to solve this problem somewhere else. Are you sure you need to navigate through four relations? Can't you change the database and/or mappings so you get the data in a more apropriate format?

Comment: I can always add a view and/or stored procedure, but the end result is a hierarchical JSON object going to the client. So I would end up recreating a hierarchy from a flattened object.

Answer (score 2):

I think you have a pretty nasty code smell going on here, but working with what you have got I wouldn't handle this in a LINQ query like that. Just for the sake of readability I'd do something like

```
myQuery = myQuery.OrderBy(p =>
  (p.HasValidFields()
    ? p.Seconds.First().Thirds.First().Forths.First().myField
    : p.myDefaultField
  ));
```

And inside of p's class

```
private bool HasValidFields
{
  get
  {
    return p.Seconds != null &&
           p.Seconds.FirstOrDefault() != null &&
           .... ;
  }
}
```